# Plugin Error - Not Sure Where to Go From Here

Tags: plugins, 404-error, dashboard, ftp

A while ago I was updating plugins for the site I work on, and the website encountered a critical error. Since then, the site and wp-admin has been non-functional. A visit comes up with this error message:

[image]

I managed to SSH into the website and rename the plugins folder to something else, hoping that this would allow the site to at least operate on a basic level, but that resulted in this 404 error:

[image]

Failing this, I tried to disable each plugin one by one by putting a "w" in front of each plugin's name. Again, each time I was met by the first "critical error" screen. I know that I first encountered this error when trying to update plugins, so I imagine this is still the culprit. Are there other steps I can take to disable these plugins? If the site encounters a critical error, is it possible that the wp-admin site may still be available? Could the culprit be something other than plugins? I'm not sure what to do, since I don't have access to the dashboard even when every plugin has been disabled.

Edit: I added a piece of the Error Log from the day things went down which may have some additional information, though I have some trouble understanding it. I found it in the "logs" folder.

[Mon Mar 18 00:52:05.040880 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 18265:tid 139819654731520] [client 114.119.129.50:39412] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  The magic method Vc_Manager::__wakeup() must have public visibility in /var/www/vhosts/(website)/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/core/class-vc-manager.php on line 203
[Mon Mar 18 00:52:05.040938 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 18265:tid 139819654731520] [client 114.119.129.50:39412] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  The magic method WC_Software_License_Client::__wakeup() must have public visibility in /var/www/vhosts/(website)/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wc-vendors-pro/includes/lib/class-wc-software-license-client.php on line 152
[Mon Mar 18 00:52:05.040942 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 18265:tid 139819654731520] [client 114.119.129.50:39412] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is not supported. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /var/www/vhosts/(website)/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/wc-vendors-pro/public/class-wcvendors-pro-form-helper.php on line 1135

I also tried to enable WP_Debug(), but the wp_config file has no text matches for "debug," so I'm not sure what to change to ensure errors are properly logged.

Comment: did you check your PHP error log to discover the error message? Without the error message it will be difficult to figure this out if it's possible at all. The issue could be outside of plugins too, without the error message we can't know

Comment: You can also enable `WP_Debug()` if you want to see the errors right on the screen.  https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/debug/debug-wordpress/